# Related Name on Base Model Object

Tags: django

I have a base model like this:

```
class FileAttachment(models.Model):
    attached_file = models.FileField(upload_to=generate_upload_path, default=None)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Account, related_name='attachments', default=None)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

I inherit it on two different models, for two different places you can attach files like this:

```
class DeliverableFileAttachment(FileAttachment):
    deliverable = models.ForeignKey(Deliverable, related_name='files')

class TaskItemFileAttachment(FileAttachment):
    taskitem = models.ForeignKey(TaskItem, related_name='files')
```

for the foreign key to author, is it okay that two different models have the same related name to account?  And is there a better way to do this ?

EDIT:

What about the opposite situation:

```
class DeliverableFileAttachment(FileAttachment):
    deliverable = models.ForeignKey(Deliverable, related_name='files')

class TaskItemFileAttachment(FileAttachment):
    taskitem = models.ForeignKey(TaskItem, related_name='files')
```

Can the related names be the same since they point to different models?

Or say I have an object like this:

```
class FileAttachment(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Account, related_name='files', default=None)
    attached_file = models.FileField(upload_to=generate_image_upload_path, default=None)

    limit = models.Q(app_label='workflow', model='project') | \
        models.Q(app_label='workflow', model='taskitem') | \
        models.Q(app_label='workflow', model='deliverable')
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(
        ContentType,
        verbose_name=_('File Attachment'),
        limit_choices_to=limit,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        related_name='files'
    )
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        verbose_name=_('related object'),
        null=True,
    )   
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

Is it okay that the related_name to author and the content_type are the same?

Comment: it depends very much on what you are trying to achieve

Comment: To be able to add uploads to two models. More than one upload.

Comment: sorry that statement isn't very clear to me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In an abstract class you shall not hardcode the related_name but do something like this:

```
class Base(models.Model):
    ...
    field= models.ForeignKey(
        OtherModel,
        related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_related",
    )
```

See the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#be-careful-with-related-name-and-related-query-name).

Comment: Yeah that's what I ended up doing.  I was imagining a list of all the "attachment" typed models related to a specific author mixed together but I realized it wouldn't work with 2 of the same related_name for different objects.  I would just have to build that mixed list myself.

Comment: What if it is the other way around, my ChildA and ChilB both have the same related name but are pointing to two different models.  Like in my edit.  Will that work?

Comment: Yes, that will be no problem. The resulting managers will be added to the models and are: DeliverableFileAttachment.files and TaskItemFileAttachment.files which are cleary distinctable.